# CakePHP API Server Response Time and FCM Push Notification

Tags: cakephp, push-notification

I have a CakePHP API Server that triggers the sending of Push Notifications to devices using the following code:

```
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key = <<Authorization Key>',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === false ){
            die('Curl failed: '. curl_error($ch));      
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

When endpoint calls are made to the Server and triggers the above code, there is a delay due to its execution (The above code works fine).

I would ideally like this time eliminated as the code does not affect the response message.  Is there a way of managing push notifications in a way that can eliminate the response time on the endpoint request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a queue. Send the task of sending the API call to a worker and you don't have to wait until it's finished.

Check this plugin out https://github.com/josegonzalez/php-queuesadilla it will allow you to create tasks and queue them. Or this CakePHP specific plugin https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue

Comment: Thanks @burzum.  I opted for the CakePHP specific plugin and solution works great!